# IE8 display:none; bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, hidden-field

I have this code in my page:

```
<form class="store_product_form" name="" method="post" action="http://www.mydomain.etc...">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input type="hidden" value="135" name="entry_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="collezione/unica/C13/portapenne" name="return_url">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="site_id">
        <inpu type="hidden" value="4194b647df2a6b56a8086303d43eac678c8d49cb" name="XID">
    </div>
    other stuff here...
</form>
```

Inputs are hidden via css:

```
input[type="hidden"] {
-moz-appearance: none;
-moz-binding: none;
-moz-user-focus: ignore;
border: 0 none;
cursor: auto;
display: none !important;
padding: 0;
}
```

Only on IE8 the containing div get showed, although it's content does not. But it eventually takes its room in the page, and this is not nice.

Unfortunately I can't modify the code, since it's injected by the CMS when the page renders.

I have surfed the web and read about the IE8 :hidden and :visible bug:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hidden-visible-broken-in-ie8

So I tried to modify the code via js, injecting some code as to make the container div hidden, but IE8 seems not to respond:

```
$(".store_product_form div input:hidden").parent().attr("style", "margin:0;padding:0;display:none;");
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you!
Carlo

Comment: You shouldn't have to apply css to a type=hidden input, they are naturally hidden. Why do you even need the container div?

Comment: Hi Kevin,unfortunately it's the CMS that applies the container div to the hidden input fields. Any idea?